# Lightroom 5 Autotone without Exposure adjustment?

Tags: lightroom

I like the Auto-tone function in Lightroom but since I take a lot of stopped down pictures in darker environments, lightroom always brightens the photos up by 1-2 stops in the exposure setting which I then have to revert.

There is another issue when I try to batch-reset the exposure in which I copy & paste the exposure setting which does not seem to work properly, but I will ask this in another question - just in case someone is suggesting this as a solution.

So the question is: Is there a possibility to do apply the Auto-tone settings to pictures but while ignoring one (specifically exposure) adjustment?

Answer (score 1):

No. Autotone is essentially the post-processing equivalent of autoexposure, auto dynamic range and auto white balance rolled into one button. It works primarily by "normalizing" the histograms in the three channels, so if you want a bottom-heavy histogram (everything important to the left), you're pretty  much out of luck. As you've noted, you are free to readjust the exposure afterwards, but adjusting the exposure is a big part of what makes Autotone work.